# Проблемы с развертыванием проекта на heroku

Tags: python, flask, socket.io, heroku

Я написал проект на flask и flask-socketio. Решил попробовать развернуть его на Heroku по ссылке https://test-viruses.herokuapp.com/ 
Проблема в том, что на главной странице есть кнопка создания комнаты, при нажатии на которую можно выбрать параметры комнаты и создать ее. Запрос создания комнаты отправляется на сервер с помощью socketio. Но создать комнату у меня получилось только с 8 попытки, а предыдущие 7 ошибка

```
GET https://test-viruses.herokuapp.com/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=1591429361376-57&sid=5499b25cc1e843418440b2ae8128f215 400 (BAD REQUEST)
```

Могу предположить что проблема в Procfile, так как я новичок и впервые с ним столкнулся. Вот Procfile:

```
web: gunicorn server:app --log-file=-
```

Сам проект на github https://github.com/victormorozov1/flask-socketio-online-game

Кто нибудь может указать проблему?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Скачайте свой проект, создайте виртуальное окружение и активируйте его.

```
python -m venv venv
venv\Scripts\activate
```

Установите имеющиеся зависимости, добавьте новую и обновите файл зависимостей

```
pip install -r requirements.txt
pip install eventlet
pip freeze > requirements.txt
```

Измените содержимое файла `Procfile` на следующее

```
web: gunicorn --worker-class eventlet -w 1 server:app
```

Измените условие в файле `server.py`

```
from app import create_app, socketio
from os import environ

app = create_app()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    host = '0.0.0.0'
    port = int(environ.get('PORT', 5000))
    socketio.run(app, host=host, port=port)
```

Сделайте коммит и отправьте на `Heroku`

```
git commit -am "some name"
git push heroku master
```

Работает без ошибки, комната создается сразу, [мой тест](https://stack-test-viruses.herokuapp.com/).

Comment: Странно, у меня не работает( приложение выложил сюда https://radiant-taiga-47785.herokuapp.com/

Comment: ошибка ```2020-06-09T11:53:37.196023+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=radiant-taiga-47785.herokuapp.com request_id=6930c002-43be-4f5c-ab8b-48c28c6dadcf fwd="89.148.241.210" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https```

Comment: Можете скинуть ссылку на ваш репозиторий?

Comment: @rew попробуйте `heroku restart` в консоле

Comment: сделал, ничего не меняется

Comment: @rew измените файл `server.py` как в обновленном посте. Должно сработать.

Comment: Спасибо, помогли)

Comment: @rew не понимаю, почему предыдущий вариант не сработал. Локально запускалось. Не забудьте завершить конкурс.